# How to access json data in console after using $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm have trouble accessing json data within the console. If for instance I wanted to type in courses[0].name or courses.length, I get the error "courses is not defined". I'm definitely missing something here but I'm unsure how to go about it. The list is generating just fine on the DOM, but I want want to access specific parts within the array.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var showData = $('#show-data');

    $.getJSON('../undergraduate/ug.json', function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      var courses = data.courses.map(function (course) {
        return course.code + ': ' + course.name;
      });


      if (courses.length) {
        var content = '<li>' + courses.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
        var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
        showData.append(list);
      }
    });
});

  <body>
    <a href="#" id="get-data">Get JSON data</a>
    <div id="show-data"></div>
  </body>
```

The json data also seems to be appearing fine initially on load within the console log:
[image]

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your browser's JS console only has access to variables declared in global scope.

Comment: Ahhh I see - thank you!